# How to load svm trained files by android NDK?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I have trained pictures using c++ opencv code but know i want to save those files somewhere in app and load those SVM trained files using the load method of SVM in opencv c++ code.First i thought i am going to save trained files in assets folder  and retrieve the files from assets but there is no absoulute path to assets folder in android apk file because the assets is zipped into apk file.
 The second choice is to save it in the android internal storage but there is also another drawback to this method i can't save large amount of data in the android internal storage.

What is the best method to save files  and load them using android ndk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal storage.  You're right, assets is only an option for read-only files shipped with the apk.  You could use eternal storage, on old versions of android there was a significant difference, not so much these days, almost nobody has an external sd card.

Comment: What's the cost of eternal storage these days? I'm tired of my hard drives _dying_.

Comment: Same price as always-  your soul.

Comment: @GabeSechan thank you i now want to save files in the asset folder and copy some files from assets(because i don't need all of them at one) into android internal storage. After using files in the internal storage in android NDK delete those files because their large sized files.Either any another best way to do this or this is fine?

Answer (score 0):

You might just use a pre-built Android wrapper like this: https://github.com/yctung/AndroidLibSVM

So you don't need to worry about JNI/NDK anymore.

Comment: Thanks, i solved the problem but is good to hear about LibSVM wrapper for android.

Comment: @Yirga how did you solve the problem, I cant load the svm file..